# Javascript replace contents in string if exists

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string that looks like this:

```
var minLength = 3;
var mystring = "This field must be {{minLength}} characters"
```

I'm curious of a good way to to detect the presence of `{{` ... `}}` and replace the contents with the minLength variable. As you can probably expect there are a number of different variables like minLength, maxLength, etc. I've tried regex but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf

Comment: Please post the expression you tried.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var values = {
    minLength: 3
};

var text = "This field must be {{minLength}} characters";
var mystring = text.replace(/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/, function(i, match) {
    return values[match];
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s2kwb/7/)

This way you can add more than one value to be replaced, you just have to add it do `values` and add `g` to the regex.

```
var values = {
    minLength: 3,
    maxLength: 10
};

var text = "This field must be min {{minLength}} characters and max {{maxLength}}";
var mystring = text.replace(/\{\{([^}]+)\}\}/g, function(i, match) {
    return values[match];
});
console.log(mystring); // This field must be min 3 characters and max 10
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s2kwb/8/)

Comment: You might return a default value, e.g. the expression or the empty string. Btw, it's `function(wholematch, firstgroup, index)…`

Answer (score 5):

```
var newString =  mystring.replace(/{{minLength}}/,minLength);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this approach:

```
var str = "This field must be {{minLength}} characters";
var result = str.replace(/{{minLength}}/,"3");​​
alert(result);
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XR4ZG/)